# In DJANGO, how do I query for records that do not exist after a certain date?

Tags: django, django-models

Assume I have a model as such:

```
class Invoices(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, ...)
    date = models.DateField()
    amount = models.FloatField()
```

I want to know all customers that **have not** purchased for the last 30 days.

Basically the inverse of this query:

```
no_sales = Invoices.objects.filter(
    date__gte=certain_date_30_days_ago
).values(
    'customer__code'
)
```

using `.exclude()` just excludes the customers who have purchased in the last 30 days but not include the people who have not purchased in the last 30 days.

Any thoughts? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**`.exclude(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) on the `Invoice` model will not work: it will not include any `Customer`s that have never bought anything. But these will still include people that bought something *before*: indeed, if a `Customer` bought 100 days ago something, and then 20 days ago, that `Customer` will still be included, since the `Invoice` for the second transaction is included, but the one 100 days ago will still be retained.

You can work on the `Customer` model with `.exclude(…)` with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

Customer.objects.exclude(
    invoices__date__gte=now()-timedelta(days=30)
)
```

This will return a `QuerySet` of `Customer`s that are *not* related to an `Invoices` record in the last 30 days.